# What parameters are used in PCL's Bilateral Filter?

Tags: ros, kinect, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to find out the parameters which are used as standard in PCL's bilateral filtering routine for Kinect images.

As I understand it, the required parameters for bilateral filtering are:

- Spatial Gaussian width
- Gaussian width in the range dimension
- Width in pixels over which the filter operates

Are these parameters hard coded into the Bilateral filtering routine? If so, where can I find them? If not, what parameters are typically used with Kinect images?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50266/what-parameters-are-used-in-pcl%27s-bilateral-filter?/) by [BillCheetham](https://answers.ros.org/users/1345/billcheetham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several bilateral filters in PCL:

1. [BilateralFilter](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/filters/include/pcl/filters/bilateral.h), no defaults.
2. [FastBilateralFilter](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/filters/include/pcl/filters/fast_bilateral.h), default is 15.0f spatial width and 0.05f range sigma.
3. [Bilateral filter in KinFu](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/gpu/kinfu/src/cuda/bilateral_pyrdown.cu), uses 4.5f spatial width and 0.03f range sigma.

---

Originally posted by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) with karma: 260 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1